# Proving chain rule using general chain rule of higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am currently following the Spivak Manifolds textbook, where it discusses the general chain rule of the following form:

$D(f\circ g)(a)=Df(g(a))\circ Dg(a)$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{p}, g:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$

How exactly does this simplify to the usual chain rule when $m=n=p=1$?

$(f\circ g)'(a)=f'(g(a))g'(a)$

I have trouble figuring out how the composition operator goes away and is replaced with multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure I've written something along these lines before, but can't find it. Anyway, recall that Spivak defines the prime notation $g'(a)$ to mean the matrix representation of the linear transformation $Dg_a:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard bases $\sigma_m=\{e_1,\dots, e_m\}$ on the domain and $\sigma_n=\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ on the target, i.e $g'(a)=[Dg_a]_{\sigma_m}^{\sigma_n}$. Now, it is a general fact of linear algebra (prove this if you're not already familiar, or look it up in a textbook, e.g Friedberg, Insel, Spence) that the matrix representations of the composition is the product of the matrix representations (actually, you can think that matrix multiplication is defined in the funny way that it is, precisely to make this statement true). So, the equation
\begin{align}
D(f\circ g)_a=Df_{g(a)}\circ Dg_a
\end{align}
is equivalent to the matrix equation
\begin{align}
[D(f\circ g)_a]_{\sigma_m}^{\sigma_p}&=[Df_{g(a)}]^{\sigma_p}_{\sigma_n}\cdot [Dg_a]^{\sigma_n}_{\sigma_m},
\end{align}
or using the just-introduced prime notation,
\begin{align}
\underbrace{(f\circ g)'(a)}_{p\times n}&=\underbrace{f'(g(a))}_{p\times m}\cdot\underbrace{ g'(a)}_{m\times n}.
\end{align}
This prime notation as the matrix-representations of the linear maps with respect to the standard basis is indeed good notation because in the case of functions $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, we have that $g$ is differentiable in the 'new' sense, (i.e existence of $Dg_a$) if and only if it is differentiable in the 'old' sense (existence of the limit $\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$ as $h\to 0$), and that in this case, the number $g'(a)$ is equal to $Dg_a(1)$, the value of the linear transformation $Dg_a:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ on the basis element $1\in\Bbb{R}$ (in fact if you re-read Spivak's motivation for defining differentiability in higher dimensions, it was motivated precisely by making this equivalence true). So, long story short, the $1\times 1$ matrix of $Dg_a$ with respect to the basis $\{1\}$ of $\Bbb{R}$ consists of the number $g'(a)$. Thus, we recover the usual 1-dimensional chain rule $(f\circ g)'(a)=f'(g(a))\cdot g'(a)$, where you can think of this as matrix-multiplication of $1\times 1$ matrices, i.e just real numbers.

The slightly more abstract way of looking at this last part is that is that for any vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, we have a canonical isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{F},V)\cong V$, namely 'evaluation at $1$', i.e the map $\Phi: \text{Hom}(\Bbb{F},V)\to V$ defined as $\Phi(T):=T(1)$ is an isomorphism (the inverse being the map $v\in V\mapsto (t\in\Bbb{F}\mapsto tv\in V)$).

Answer (score 0):

$Df(g(a))\circ Dg(a)$ is composition of linear transformations. In the 1-dimensional case, a linear transformation can be identified with scalar multiplication (after choosing bases), and then composition of scalar multiplications is scalar multiplication by the multiplication of the scalars ... that was a bit tortuously expressed.

Same explanation, slightly reworded: $Df(g(a))\circ Dg(a)$ is composition is a composition of linear transformations, and thus corresponds to matrix multiplication of the associated matrices in some basis... this is why matrix multiplication is defined the strange way that it is. For the 1 dimensional case, the derivative (represented as a matrix) is a 1x1 matrix, i.e a number.