# Why is the chain rule in 1D different than for total derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $f, g$ be smooth real valued functions of one variable. Then the chain rule says that
$$h' = (f \circ g)' = (f' \circ g) \cdot g'.$$

Now, more generally, let $u: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $v: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be smooth, and suppose $a$ is some vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Then the chain rule says that:
$$D_a(u \circ v) = D_{v(a)}u \circ D_av$$
where $D_av$ denotes the directional derivative of $v$ along $a$.

Why are the two chain rules not the same? Is there a geometric argument that would explain this? How would one show that in the case where $m = n = k = 1$ that the two chain rules are equivalent?

Comment: They do agree, when you recall that derivatives are linear maps, and in 1D linear maps are just multiplying by a constant, so composing them is equivalent to multiplying the constants

Comment: @jlammy I'm sorry I don't exactly follow your comment, would you be able to elaborate in more detail?

Comment: See [Proving chain rule using general chain rule of higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4450674/568204). It's a matter of basic linear algebra to see how the special case arises.

Comment: The derivative is the "best linear approximation" to a function, formally $D_af$ is the unique linear map s.t. $f(a+h)=f(a)+D_af(h)+o(\|h\|)$. The only linear maps $T:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, i.e. the only functions with $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ are of the form $T(x)=\lambda x$ some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Then composing two such maps, say $T_1(x)=\lambda_1x$ and $T_2(x)=\lambda_2(x)$ is equivalent to multiplying the constants: $T_1\circ T_2(x)=\lambda_1\lambda_2 x$.

Comment: @jlammy I see it now, thank you!